# .NET setup.exe project and promptrestart msi flag

Tags: .net, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a setup.exe project that I run with the following command-line arguments to install:

> /passive /promptrestart CMDCODE=InstallComplete

I've also tried this:

```
/quiet /promptrestart CMDCODE=InstallComplete
```

In both cases, if a reboot is required, the user is not asked or even given a warning, it just starts after install is complete.

I suspect it might be because promptrestart was added later, and MS never updated setup.exe to pass that along when calling the MSI.  Can anyone confirm or deny this?  Does the option work for you?  Is there another option I should use instead?

The CMDCODE= part is just something we use internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have only tested on XP so far, but it appears changing to this works:

> /qb /promptrestart CMDCODE=InstallComplete

So changing /quiet or /passive to /qb.  I don't really need an "always passive" install, in fact I wish it would prompt if a newer version already installed, or for any errors, I just don't want it to ask the user any questions under a normal install (no reboot, no errors).

Comment: That should work. It didn't work with `/quiet` and `/passive` because they imply no interaction with the user at all, so Windows Installer implies there's no user to press a button in this mode. With `/qb`, it's implied there's a user who could take an action if it's necessary.